# A Problem Distribution Function

Tags: probability, functions

If I have a probability density function like this

$w(x) = 1 - |x| $if $|x| \leq 1$ or

$ w(x)=0$ if $|x|\geq 1$,

what's the value of the distribution function F(x)? 
I mean that I calculated $F(x) = ∞$ for$ x ∈ (-∞, 0] $ because $F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{0} w(x)dx $ . I think this is a nonsense because the maximum value of $F(x)$ is 1.
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to draw it, perhaps that'd be enlightening enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solving the inequality $|x|\leq 1$.

If $x<0$, then $-x \leq 1 \Rightarrow x\geq -1$.

If $x\geq 0$, then $x\leq 1 $

Thus $1-|x| \,  \text{,  if} -1 \leq x \leq 1$

The range is from 0 to 1, because  $f(-1)=f(1)=0$ and $f(0)=1$

If $x <0$, then $1-|x|=1-(-x)=1+x$

If $x \geq 0$, then $1-x=1-x$

$f(x)=\begin{cases}1+x\text{, if} -1 \leq x < 0 \\ 1-x \, \text{, if} \ 0 \leq x \leq 1 \\ 0 \text{, elsewhere} \end{cases} $

I think you can calculate F(x) by your own.

Comment: thank you. that helped me. i see now that i did a mistake when i solved the inequality.